# Using WCF services as Restful Architecture

Tags: ajax, rest, wcf, post

I am trying to convert my wcf services to a restful architecture. I started by converting a service called ConnectToApplication which checks user permission for authentification purposes in order to support POST requests. While trying Ajax to query the service using the following javascript code:

```
   var formData={"userName":"admin", "password":"act;2016@","ApplicationName":"actior"}


        $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost:10220/AdministrationService/ConnectToApplication",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,



            success: function (data) { 
            alert('success');
            },
              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                           alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
               } 

        });
```

I got an HTTP 400(Bad request) with the following error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception
>   message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format
>   'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml';
>   'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been
>   configured on the binding. See the documentation of
>   WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more
>   details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message
>   message, Object[] parameters) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Here is my metadata for endpoint configuration:

```
  [OperationContract]
         [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "ConnectToApplication/")]

        UserPermessionDTO ConnectToApplication(string userName, string password, string ApplicationName);
```

Here is my WCF configuration:

```
    <services>
      <service name="ActiorServeurConsoleApp.AdministrationService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ActiorServeurConsoleApp.IAdministrationService"
                      behaviorConfiguration="web">
              <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
            </endpoint>

            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:10220/AdministrationService/" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
    <services>


    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>

  <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the content type for the post as

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Also you can look at tools like fiddler and possibly postman to check you types  and also test your service.

Comment: I tryed this. However, I got the HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect error.

Comment: Does the call ever hit your code or it fails before it even gets in?

Comment: One of the best resources I found when debugging WCF services is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-inspect-or-modify-parameters , you should be able to query the wcf service to see what is being sent to your service.